# How to get list of available --with-x for configure.sh script?

Tags: autoconf

Autoconf script (./configure) often is created so it can build software with different set of components. For example, while building lynx web browser i can use `./configure --with-openssl` to trigger corresponding `#ifdef` in app source code and make it with open SSL support.

If i have a third-party `./configure.sh` file, is it any way to get a list of supported `--with` statements from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the `configure` script was built by autoconf, you can just type `./configure --help` to see what `--with` and `--enable` options are available.